# Duda acerca de manejo de ficheros en C con struct dinamico

Tags: c, archivo, manejo-de-memoria, struct

Como ven mi código es para cargar datos de un fichero.txt a una estructura dinámica, pero está el siguiente inconveniente: resulta que en el momento que en mi bloc de notas quiero además de añadirle el nombre y la edad a la persona, le quiero añadir digamos la estatura por ejemplo, declarando su atributo en el struct como ustedes pueden observar. No se puede leer el valor.

Es decir, básicamente no sé cómo hacer para poder manejar cargar más de dos valores en mi struct dinámico con archivos. Leo el archivo hasta conseguirme con un salto de línea para guardar los caracteres y seguidamente proceder a leer los enteros pero el caso acá es que no es un solo entero lo que hay después del string sino 2. Adjunto el código y los errores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// ARCHIVOS

// METER ELEMENTOS DE UN FICHERO A UNA ESTRUCTURA DE DATOS , es decir esto es CARGAR DATOS DE ARCHIVO A ESTRUCTURA EN C.
typedef struct{
    char *nombre;
    int edad;
    int estatura;
    
}trabajadores;

trabajadores *trab; //Declaracion lista dinamica de trabajadores

//PROTOTIPOS:
void copiar (char temp[], int i);
void vaciar (char temp[]);

int main()
{
    char temp[50];
    char aux;
    int cont = 0;
    int i,j;
    
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("Nombres.txt","r");
    
    if (f == NULL){
        printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero...");
        exit(1);
    }
    //LEER EL ARCHIVO:
    while (!feof(f)){
        fgets(temp,50,f);   //Fgets, para leer todas las lineas, las va a almacenar en un String por tanto necesito un string aux
        cont++; //Cada vez que leamos una linea del archivo/fichero incremento el contdor en 1
    }
    //Despues de leer los elementos del fichero, el cursor se encuentra en el ultimo elemento, yo no quiero que eso ocurra
    //Por tanto debo devolver el cursor al principio con lo siguiente: 
    rewind(f); //Rewind, te pone el cursor al principio de nuevo. 
    
    
    // METIENDO  LOS DATOS DEL ARCHIVO EN MI ESTRUCTURA DINAMICA: 
    
    // UNA VEZ QUE YA YO SE CUANTOS TRABAJADORES TIENE EL FICHERO, PUES YA PUEDO ASIGNAR LA MEMORIA DINAMICA
    trab = (trabajadores*)malloc(cont*sizeof(trabajadores));
    
    if (trab == NULL){
        printf("No se ha podido asginar el espacio de memoria necesario !!  ");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    // Leemos el nombre y la edad de los elementos del archivo
    // Salgo del bucle FOR, cuando llego al final del fichero
    
    printf(".::DATOS RECOGIDOS DEL ARCHIVO::.\n");
    for (i=0; !feof(f); i++){ //Leo 1 a 1 los elementos y los meto en la variable auxiliar temp 
        // Pero sucede algo.. TEMP ya tenia informacion, por tanto tengo que vaciarla. 
        vaciar(temp);
        
        aux = '0'; //Inicializo auxiliar antes
        for (j = 0; aux != '\n'; j++){ //Otro bucle for para recorrer a nueva variable aux, si es distinta de - sigo, sino paro
            aux = fgetc(f);  //fgetc lee letra por letra los elementos del fichero, cuando llegue al - saldra del ciclo
            if (aux != '\n'){  //Si aux es distinto del guion....
                temp[j] = aux;  //Los elementos del AUX se copian y pegan en el temp.
            }             
        }
        // Temp va a tener el nombre, este nombre lo quiero meter dentro de la estructura 
        copiar(temp,i);
        
        //Para obtener la edad hacemos lo siguiente, ya que nos encontramos despues del  '-':
        fgets(temp,4,f); //Se le pasa el 4 como longitud ya que va a coger los dos numeros , el '/n' + el '/0'
        //Pero , recordemos que esos numeros en realidad no son enteros, sino caracteres 
        // Por tanto para convertir de caracteres a enteros: 
        // Por tanto uso la funcion atoi. Ella debe tener una variable donde recojer el numero convertido
        trab[i].edad = atoi(temp); //Almacena en trab.edad la edad en enteros del personal.
        trab[i].estatura = atoi(temp);
        //fINALMENTE Mostramos por pantalla los datos totales obtenidos: 
        
        printf("Empleado: %i - Nombre: %s  - Edad:%i  - Estatura:%d \n",i,trab[i].nombre,trab[i].edad,trab[i].estatura);
    }
    
    free(trab[i].nombre);
    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Funcion para vaciar lo que tenga la variable auxiliar para asi yo poder meter los elementos del archivo en la estructura
void vaciar (char temp[]){
    int i;
    
    for (i=0; i<50; i++){
        temp[i] = '\0'; //En cada uno de estos elementos voy a meterle el '\0' para borrar todo lo que tenga.
    }
    
}

void copiar (char temp[], int i){ //Metemos el contenido de la variable temp dentro del string dinamico nombre
    //Reservo espacio para string dinamico nombre
    int N = strlen(temp)+1;
    //En N tenemos ya cual es la longitud de temp
    // Reserva de espacio de memoria  
    trab[i].nombre = (char*)malloc(N*sizeof(char)); //Reservo la memoria solamente para el nombre del trabajador. 
    
    if (trab[i].nombre == NULL){
        printf("NO SE PUDO RESERVAR EL ESPACIO DE MEMORIA ");
        exit(1);
    }
    //El i sirve como identificador del trabajdor que vamos a meter en la estructura 
    //Procedemos a copiar el string de temp a nombre 
    strcpy(trab[i].nombre,temp);
}
```

Output : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Formato de mi archivo .txt]

Comment: ¿Cómo están estructurados los datos en el archivo?

Comment: Estan separados por un salto de línea, como acá:                           
Agustin\n 
21\n
Manuel\n
30\n

Comment: El ejemplo que pones no incluye estatura ¿Seguro que esos son tus datos?

Comment: Uy disculpame, puse el que funcionaba sin la estatura . Serían estos :             Agustin\n
21\n
170\n
Manuel\n
30\n
180\n

Comment: Creo que sería mejor que incluyeras esa información en la pregunta, no en los comentarios.

Comment: Si , ya lo puse para que se viera mejor. Creo que el error viene de la variable temp pero no puedo aun ver que es lo que pasa exactamente